# find failed predicate in prolog - automated debug mode?

Tags: prolog

How to find if some predicate in long computation return fail  ?  Is it possible to do it using something like debug mode ?  I searched in google, but no results.

Comment: You can use `trace`. It will show very clearly if a call inside fails in the process. But be aware that failure of various calls is a normal part of a properly working Prolog predicate if it does anything interesting at all.

Comment: I don't think there's a facility that just traces the failure calls. It would be hard to tell what was going on, though, without knowing the execution flow around a failure. Thus, the `trace` is quite useful in this regard.

Comment: I know `trace`, but here it doesn't help me

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in more detail what you need? Your question is a bit terse. :) Explain, particularly, why `trace` doesn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For SWI-Prolog there is the possibility to [hook into debugger](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%27prolog%3Adebug_control_hook%27/1). If you visit the site, take a look at the context: a funny [Hackers Corner](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=hack) section.